# Prove for $abc$-triples that $c\leq rad(abc)^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, abc-conjecture

Prove for $abc$-triples that $c\leq \text{rad}(abc)^2$. $\text{rad}(abc)$ and $\text{rad}(x)$ means here the product of all prime factors of $x$.

(edit 2)

The above holds for:

$16+5=21 \leq (2*5*3*7)^2$

$3^2+4^2=5^2 \leq (3*2*5)^2$

$1+99=100 \leq (2*11)^2$

I am looking for a general condition which would at least satisfy the above examples.

Comment: Is $rad(abc)$ defined as $rad(a)\cdot rad(b)\cdot rad(c)$? Or is it defined as the product of prime factors of $abc$? If $a=4,b=6,c=9$, for example, the two are different.

Comment: If the three dots just mean rad(b) why not write rad(b)?

Comment: Okay now the question is clear, but $a=3,b=9,c=81$ would be an easy counter example.

Comment: @cr001 You're right, that expansion holds only in special cases. Corrected.

Comment: @Justpassingby Who cares, both are equivalent? Why have you written "If the three dots just mean rad(b) why not write rad(b)?" instead of "Why not replace '...' with rad(b)?"? Why would you ask questions which penetrate to someone's syntactic taste?

Comment: No, an abc-triple has to satisfy $a+b=c$, e.g., $(a,b,c)=(1,8,9)$.

Comment: Oh did not know that is a specific term. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am not sure what you're trying to say, still $3+9\neq 81$

Comment: Look [here](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/abcLahore032013.pdf) for the term "abc-triple". Of course, $(3,9,81)$ is not an abc-triple. The numbers must be coprime, too. Only then the statement with the radical makes sense.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's what I am trying to say. Please specify the user you're responding to by using the @ sign and the username, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Joe The abc-conjecture has a related conjecture, namely that perhaps $c<Rad(abc)^{7/4}$ for $(a,b,c)$-triples, i.e., with $a+b=c$ and $a,b,c$ coprime.

Comment: Just if you're trying to look for which $\epsilon$ the abc-conjecture is proven, I think (maybe my knowledge is limited) that the upper bound of $c$ for the moment  is exponential, $$\log c \leq C R^{1/3}(\log R)^{3}\implies c\leq e^{(R^{1/3}\cdots)} $$ where $R=rad(abc)$ which is due to Stewart-Yu Kunrui. Anyway I don't think that you will find a counter example either because the best highest quality triple is $$
    a = 2,
    b = 310·109 = 6,436,341,
    c = 235 = 6,436,343,
    rad(abc) = 15042. $$

Comment: Continuing my comment, my last counter example gives $$c = rad(abc)^{1.62\cdots}$$ and there is no known $a,b,c$ triples such that $c\geq rad(abc)^{1.63}$

Comment: @Elaqqad Thank you guys for your comments, I appreciate those a lot. Please check out my latest edit, could you comment on it?

Comment: @Wojowu Yes I do, I'm sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is unkwown whether or not there exists an $(a,b,c)$-triple, i.e., coprime numbers $a,b,c$ with $a+b=c$ and $c\ge a,b$, such that
$$
c>rad(abc)^2.
$$ 
So the formulation "prove that it holds" is quite unrealistic. For references on these claims see, say, [here](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/ABCpresentation.pdf). This is closely related to the so-called "explicit" $abc$-conjecture.